# How to calculate a discount in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, discount

I wanted to make it change to .18 .28 and .38 if the value its >= than 1000

So if the value its =< 999, it will keep this price!

```js
jQuery(".superannuation-calc").noUiSlider({
   range: [0, 10000]
   ,start: 0
   ,handles: 1
   ,step: 1
   ,slide: function(){
  var value = jQuery(this).val()
     ,yr1 = addCommas(value * .19)
     ,yr100 = addCommas(value * .39)
     ,yr10 = addCommas(value * .29);
     jQuery(this).siblings(".amt").text(value);
     jQuery(this).parents("tr").find(".subtotal-item-1").text(yr1);
     jQuery(this).parents("tr").find(".subtotal-item-10").text(yr10);
     jQuery(this).parents("tr").find(".subtotal-item-100").text(yr100);
     calcTotals();
    }
  });
```

```html
<div class="calc-table"> 
  <table class="calc-tbl"> 
     <thead> 
        <tr>
           <td class="calc-tbl-title">Compra de Zennys, lembra que você deve multiplicar o valor escolhido por 1.000.000</td> 
           <td class="calc-tbl-col1">Thor</td> 
           <td class="calc-tbl-col2">Asgard</td> 
           <td class="calc-tbl-col3">Odin</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make use of the ternary operator.

```
var value = jQuery(this).val(),
    yr1 = value >=1000 ? addCommas(value * .18) : value,
    yr100 = value >=1000 ? addCommas(value * .39) : value,
    yr10 = value >=1000 ?  addCommas(value * .28) : value;
```

Or you could try this:

```
var value = jQuery(this).val(),
    yr1 = value, 
    yr100 = value,
    yr10 = value;

if( value>= 1000 ){
    yr1 = addCommas(value * .18);
    yr100 = addCommas(value * .39);
    yr10 = addCommas(value * .28);
}
```

Comment: Worked, now how do I make it only to a decimal place?